# How to find the probability a random window encloses the mean of its distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

I thought this was going to be straightforward but I've obviously been staring at it too long and got stuck!

I am considering a random variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$ drawn from a symmetric distribution $f(x)$ with mean $\mu$ and support in $(-\infty,+\infty)$.  For some values of $x$, the inequality $x_0-\delta \leq x \leq x_0$, where $\delta>0$ is a real constant, will hold.  I would like to derive the pdf for the random variable $y$ which satisfies this inequality.

I am thinking that the required density function should take the form
$$
g(y) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
0 & , & y<x_0-\delta \\
? & , & x_0-\delta \leq y \leq x_0 \\
0 & , & y > x_0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
with $g(x_0-\delta)=\max_\mathbb{R} g(y)$ and $g(x_0)=0$, and clearly $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(y)\,\text{d}y=1$.  But I am going round in circles figuring out what form $g(y)$ takes in $(x_0-\delta, x_0)$.

Comment: You've described a single event, not a random variable. What is the r.v. whose density function you're trying to define?

Comment: You're right, I've updated the question,, it was not expressed properly.  Let me know if it's clearer?

Comment: I see. Hint: you (presumably) want your new density function to have the same shape as the old one in that interval, so you just need to scale up the old one (multiply it by a constant) so that it integrates to 1.

Comment: Hmm that's where I'm not sure.  I actually don't want the new density function to be the same as the old one.  I have put in my final couple of sentences in the question what I suspect the new density should look roughly like, but again, I am conscious that I may not be describing the problem correctly.

Comment: I'm now thinking it is nothing more than the uniform distribution.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, many different functions satisfy the conditions you've stated, and it's not clear what your goal is. Why do you want your density to be maximized at $x_0-\delta$? Do you want the new r.v. to be related to the original one at all?

Comment: Thanks Karl for your interest in this question.  From your comments and those of @ConMan I realise now that the question I have posted is ill-posed and I have concluded that I need to rethink the formulation of the problem.  My goal was to try to use a probabilistic argument to describe the risk of a proximity to the 'centre' location of a distribution whose pdf closely approximates an otherwise intractable function.  If such a problem continues to interest you, you might like to look at 'Mahalabonis distance', which is closely related.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, notice that if $x \leq x_0 \leq x + \delta$, then $x_0 - \delta \leq x \leq x_0$.

Comment: Well, yes, that is very much in amongst my various approaches and presumably leads to $\mathbb{P}(x \leq x_0) \left[ 1 - \mathbb{P}(x \leq x_0-\delta)  \right]$.  But then I got into doubts about whether this should be treated as a conditional probability problem.

Comment: If the distribution of $x$ is $f(x)$, then $P(a \leq x \leq b) = \int_a^b f(x) dx$, no?

Comment: Sure, of course.  I realise now I haven't been clear enough in the question.  What I am trying to find is an expression for the density function in $(x_0-\delta,x_0)$.  I will edit the question to clarify.  Thank you.